# android sqlite strftime long month name

Tags: android, sqlite, date, time, strftime

With this query, I get from the database, the month in numeric format. can I get the month in long format? 'MMMM'

```
private List<String> ottieniMesi(){
    List<String> result1 = new LinkedList<String>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()).getReadableDatabase();

    String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT strftime('%m',"+Table.DATE+") FROM "+Table.TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    while (c.moveToNext()){
        result1.add(c.getString(0));

    }
    db.close();
    return result1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. [sqlite date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) do not support such conversion.

Consider doing the conversion in your application code instead.

For example:

```
int monthNumber = ...; // the value from query
monthNumber--; // convert to 0-based for Calendar
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);
String monthName = c.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I convert the result of this query?

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

You can get the name of the month using [`java.time.Month#getDisplayName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html#getDisplayName-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Locale-).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // An arbitrary month number for demo - you are getting this value from the DB
        int monthNumber = 0;

        Month month = Month.of(monthNumber + 1);
        String monthName = month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH);

        System.out.println(monthName);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
January
```

**Note:** This code assumes that you are getting `0`-based `monthNumber` i.e. 0 for Jan, 1 for Feb and so on. If it is not the case, use just `monthNumber` instead of `monthNumber + 1`.

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>